# Using this.context in React

Tags: reactjs

It’s not an *official* API ([yet](http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/03/28/the-road-to-1.0.html#context)!), but `context` can be super useful in React mixins. However, its behavior and contents are not entirely intuitive for me.

Where do the contents of `this.context` come from?

*(As of this writing, React is at version 0.12)*

---

**Update:** A long time has passed! Context has been an official React API for some time now. It’s [documented here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs have the best info.
http://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

In short this is what context is.

```
Top Parent
  |
  |
  |
Inter Parent
  |
  |
  |
Immediate Parent
  |
  |
  |
Child
```

Say you need to pass a prop from **Top Parent** to **Child**. You would need to set it as prop to Immediate Parent and Inter parent. And if it's 2 way then props needs to be passed both ways.

Context allows you to bypass this and pass data directly from **Top Parent** to **Child**

This becomes more useful when multiple childs need the same prop but each is deep nested

Comment: **React-router adds router object to the context for routing**

Answer (score 8):

I was looking into this too earlier, `this.context` is a set of attributes that are implicitly passed down to its children rather than passing the properties explicitly. You can look at the React testing suites to see how they behave:

[https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0.12-stable/src/core/**tests**/ReactCompositeComponent-test.js#L1101](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0.12-stable/src/core/__tests__/ReactCompositeComponent-test.js#L1101)

[https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0.12-stable/src/core/**tests**/ReactElement-test.js#L100](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/0.12-stable/src/core/__tests__/ReactElement-test.js#L100)

I also found this article by Dave King helpful in understanding some of the exposed methods and behaviors:
http://web.archive.org/web/20150319074927/https://www.tildedave.com/2014/11/15/introduction-to-contexts-in-react-js.html

Comment: Dave King's article is great

Comment: The Dave King article is visible at http://web.archive.org/web/20150319074927/https://www.tildedave.com/2014/11/15/introduction-to-contexts-in-react-js.html. I am going to suggest an edit to the post to fix the dead link

Answer (score 5):

If you don't mind, I have a post on React's context
https://dlinau.wordpress.com/2015/07/19/take-a-deeper-look-into-context-in-react-js

> In short, a context is an object with attributes that are implicitly passed down from an element to all of its children and grandchildren.
>
> To share data/attributes with children components with context, a component defines the attribute names and data types available in the context by defining the attribute childContextTypes. It also need to define getChildContext method that returns the data values of attributes in the context. The keys in childContextTypes must be exactly the same set of keys in the object returned by getChildContext method.
>
> When a child component wants to use data from parent’s context, it must first declare what it wants to use explicitly by defining the attribute contextTypes.
>   contextTypes is an object specifying the name and type of attributes it want to use.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference